# Change name of photo album that Facebook app generates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using the graph API to share to Facebook, Facebook aggregates any photos uploaded to a user's timeline by your app into an album with your app's name. For example, if your app is called `ACME Co`, all the photos that you've shared to a user's timeline will be placed in an album called `ACME Co Photos`.

What I'd like to know is if there is a way to edit/control the name of this album? For example, my app is still called `ACME Co`, but I want the album to be called something else (e.g. `Office Happy Hour Photos`).

At least according to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/album#update), you can't edit the name of an existing album, however I'd still like to know if it's possible change the name of this album when it's initially created. Thanks!

Comment: No there is no way to do that

Comment: I didn't think there was, but my boss insisted I inquire anyways.

Comment: Well you could create a new album for the user first - that allows you to specify the album name. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/albums#Creating